# Exception RuntimeError in Rack application object (Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, passenger

I'm trying to deploy a Rails application on a Digital Ocean VPS but I keep getting this error in my log when I try to `sudo service nginx restart`.

```
Exception RuntimeError in Rack application object (Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`)
```

I have generated my secret_key_base token. These are my secrets.yml and database.yml files:

**appname/shared/config/database.yml**

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: myappname_production
  username: deploy
  password: mypassword
```

**appname/shared/config/secrets.yml**

```
production:
  secret_key_base: e0f6563b486e81d04ec9341854a26b8342a61675df8f3*********
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error? I'm at a loss here

Comment: What happens when you take it out of the shared folder and have it in appname/config? It may be  a case of it just not finding the file. If that's not the answer, triplecheck your syntax

Comment: This seems to have fixed it :) It didn't work for a while but after I restarted the server it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Also the secrets.yml file got deleted every time I redeployed the server because it wasn't in my local development folder